# chartjs Adding percentages to Pie Chart Legend

Tags: charts, chart.js

What's the simplest way to add the percentage values to the legend labels?

I believe it would use  generateLabels: function (chart) {}, can anyone provide a clean example?

Comment: will you please provide the code currently used to draw the chart? and an example of the percentage value you would like to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be any native way to show the percentages, but it's quite straightforward to calculate and set them as the labels:

```js
const data = [1, 2, 3],
  // ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce
  total = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue),
  // ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
  labels = data.map(value => Math.round((value / total) * 100) + '%');

new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      data: data
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" height="75"></canvas>
```

(Note: the use of `Math.round()` could cause certain number sets not to equal 100% when summed.)

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly.

I added:

    const cats = ['A','B','C'];
    labels = data.map(value => cats[value - 1] + ' ' + Math.round((value / total) * 100) + '%');

This gave me the category and the value which is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

> If you already have an array of legends, you can add the percentage to it with this code. Here **i** is the index of the current element in the array.

```
data=[2,4,5,7];
legend=['A','B','C','D']
total = data.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => parseInt(accumulator) + parseInt(currentValue));
labelsvalues = data.map(function(value,i){
let p= Math.round((value / total) * 100) + '%';
return legend[i]+' '+p;
});
```